# SMACK 4.2.4 connection with ejabberd through TLS

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I have been working with ejabberd and smack 4.2.4. It was fine until I implemented TLS certificate from LetsEncrypt. Now it gives SSL handshake error.

Same secure connection works for iOS and other clients if I enable TLS in connection configuration.

I searched but could find any idea how to fix this. Please help for Android connection.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent time and finally got this solution working for me.

```
configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext(context);
configBuilder.setCustomSSLContext(sslContext);


public SSLContext getSSLContext(Context context ) throws IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
        CertificateFactory cf = null;

        try {
            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.chain); // R.raw.chain is CA Root Certificate added in RAW resources folder

        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        Certificate ca = null;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.d(TAG, "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext;

    }
```

Comment: From where do we get the "chain" file?